# What is the meaning of "each known and individual except the gaps" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I encountered the boldfaced expression while reading, and would like to know what it means:

> “No! Not the Teeth!”
>
> The teeth were here, inside his mouth. He felt them with his tongue,
> the double barrier of bone, **each known and individual except the
> gaps**—and there they persisted as a memory if one troubled to think.
> But to lie on a row of teeth in the middle of the sea——

- William Golding, *Pincher Martin*, Chapter 6

I guess "each" refers to "each tooth." If my guess is right, I understand that his each tooth is known and individual. But I cannot grasp how his teeth are so "except the gaps."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would interpret it as "each of his teeth is known and individual, but the gaps are not known and individual."  That is, the character is familiar with each of his teeth, but the gaps between his teeth are not something he thinks of as having independent existences or is familiar with.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. So, for him, each of his teeth is familiar (=known) and independent beings (=individual), but the gaps are not familiar and independent. Now I think I understood it all thanks to you. I guess the concept of "teeth" is significant in this novel, and would like to learn how it is connected to the novel as I continue reading...